# How to find N points on an infinite axis so that sum of distances from M points to its nearest N is smallest?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

Consider there are N houses on a single road. I have M lightpoles. Given that M < N. Distance between all adjacent houses are different. Lightpole can be placed at the house only. And I have to place all lightpoles at house so that sum of distances from each house to its nearest lightpole is smallest. How can I code this problem?

After a little research I came to know that I have to use dynamic programming for this problem. But I don't know how to approach it to this problem.

Comment: There exists a rather simple iterative algorithm that converges to a local minimum.There is no guarantee that this minimum is global. Are you interested in this kind of solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a naive dynamic program with search space `O(n^2 * m)`. Perhaps others know of another speedup? The recurrence should be clear from the function `f` in the code.

JavaScript code:

```js
// We can calculate these in O(1)
// by using our prefixes (ps) and
// the formula for a subarray, (j, i),
// reaching for a pole at i:
//
// ps[i] - ps[j-1] - (A[i] - A[j-1]) * j
//
// Examples:
// A:  [1,2,5,10]
// ps: [0,1,7,22]
// (2, 3) =>
//   22 - 1 - (10 - 2) * 2
//   = 5
//   = 10-5
// (1, 3) =>
//   22 - 0 - (10 - 1) * 1
//   = 13
//   = 10-5 + 10-2
function sumParts(A, j, i, isAssigned){
  let result = 0
  for (let k=j; k<=i; k++){
    if (isAssigned)
      result += Math.min(A[k] - A[j], A[i] - A[k])
    else
      result += A[k] - A[j]
  }
  return result
}

function f(A, ps, i, m, isAssigned){
  if (m == 1 && isAssigned)
    return ps[i]
    
  const start = m - (isAssigned ? 2 : 1)
  const _m = m - (isAssigned ? 1 : 0)
  let result = Infinity
    
  for (let j=start; j<i; j++)
    result = Math.min(
      result,
      sumParts(A, j, i, isAssigned)
        + f(A, ps, j, _m, true)
    )
  
  return result
}

var A = [1, 2, 5, 10]
var m = 2

var ps = [0]
for (let i=1; i<A.length; i++)
  ps[i] = ps[i-1] + (A[i] - A[i-1]) * i

var result = Math.min(
  f(A, ps, A.length - 1, m, true),
  f(A, ps, A.length - 1, m, false))

console.log(`A:  ${ JSON.stringify(A) }`)
console.log(`ps: ${ JSON.stringify(ps) }`)
console.log(`m:  ${ m }`)
console.log(`Result: ${ result }`)
```

Comment: this code is working, but can you explain what is happening here ? What is importance of ps[] array ?

Comment: @KamalPancholi the `ps` variable is a special kind of prefix sums that shows the sum of all distances for elements from index 0 to `i`. In this code, it is only used for `if (m == 1 && isAssigned)` to return the sum of all distances from the beginning to `i`, but I explain in the comments how we can also use it to transform the loop in `sumParts` into a single formula for the sum of all distances for a subarray with one pole on its right side (we would need a second, reversed `ps` for when the pole is on the left).

Comment: @KamalPancholi if `i` is assigned, though, we would need to use binary search or have a pre-calculated table to find the point, `p`, where we split the subarray into distances from `p` to `i` and from `p-1` down to `j` since each house correlates with the pole closer to it.

Answer (score 0):

I got you covered bud. I will write to explain the dynamic programming algorithm first and if you are not able to code it, let me know.

A-> array containing points so that A[i]-A[i-1] will be the distance between A[i] and A[i-1]. A[0] is the first point. When you are doing memoization top-down, you will have to handle cases when you would want to place a light pole at the current house or you would want to place it at a lower index. If you place it now, you recurse with one less light pole available and calculate the sum of distances with previous houses. You handle the base case when you are not left with any ligh pole or you are done with all the houses.

Comment: Please at least formalise the recurrence if you are not providing any pseudo or regular code. By "formalise" I mean write a mathematical formula that expresses the general case of the recurrence. As it is, this answer is unclear.